# Изменение рамки когда select нажат

Tags: html, css

Подскажите пожалуйста, как изменить цвет синей рамки когда select нажат?
http://joxi.ru/Q2KQLQKh4xMdyr

```html
<select style="border: none;outline: none;cursor: pointer;-webkit-appearance: none">
<option>Текст</option>
<option>Текст 2</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не у всех эта синия рамка есть. Полностью стилизовать селект с опциями нельзя, но можно нарисовать свой, с любыми стилями. Или взять что-то отсюда http://plugins.jquery.com/tag/select/

Answer (score 0):

попробуй на select или на option:

```
outline: none;
```

Честно говоря, сам не делал конкретно на селекте, но на инпутах еще не подводило.